# Sliding GUI.HorizontalSlider also moves Camera with FreeCamera script

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, rendering

I have a `GUi.HorizontalSlider` in my scene and have a camera with a `FreeCamera` script attached. This causes the problem that when I slide the `HorizontalSlider`, the camera also rotates according to the slider mouse movement.

How can I slide the GUI.HorizontalSlider without making the camera rotate?

```
    var vSliderValue = 0.0F;
    var R : Transform;
    var L : Transform;

    function OnGUI () {
        vSliderValue = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(25, 25, 150, 150), vSliderValue, 0.0F, -180.0F);
        R.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y = vSliderValue;

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine in C# and javascript as well. Just changed `R.transform.rotation.eulerAngles` to `R.transform.eulerAngles` for C# (samething working in JS). **There must be some code where you are also transforming the camera in same script.**

Comment: No, I am not changing the camera anywhere else.

Comment: Try your sample code in new project as I have tried it in new project and found it working as u wanted.